# How can I display the calc menu when `calc-embedded-mode` is enabled?

Tags: latex, calc, menus

I find `calc-embedded-mode` handy for typing math from LaTeX mode. As I use it very little, I would like to have the calc menu in integrated mode. The menu remains in latex mode which is useless. I tried to activate without success the `calc-menu function which must have another use than the one I want.

Comment: Not sure I understood what you mean, so the answer is a stab in the dark. If I'm completely off the mark, maybe you can explain what you want in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calc menu is only visible when the major mode of the buffer is `calc-mode`. If you want it visible in other modes, you have to lift that restriction, e.g. here's how to redefine it so that it is visible in `latex-mode` (as well as in `calc-mode`):

```el
(easy-menu-define
  calc-menu
  calc-mode-map
  "Menu for Calc."
  (list "Calc"
        :visible '(or (eq major-mode 'latex-mode)
                      (eq major-mode 'calc-mode))
        calc-arithmetic-menu
        calc-scientific-function-menu
        calc-algebra-menu
        calc-graphics-menu
        calc-vectors-menu
        calc-units-menu
        calc-variables-menu
        calc-stack-menu
        calc-errors-menu
        calc-modes-menu
        calc-help-menu
        ["Reset"
         (progn
           (require 'calc-ext)
           (call-interactively 'calc-reset))
         :help "Reset Calc to its initial state"]
        ["Quit" calc-quit]))
```

Do `C-h v calc-menu` and look at the definition of the menu in `calc-menu.el`.

Comment: You understood the problem correctly. I created a function and added it as a hook to calc-embedded mode. Your solution should be more complete if you add this.

Comment: Feel free to modify the answer (or add another answer): since you have already done it, it should be easy for you to write up - I'd have to spend more time on this (which I can ill afford :-) ) to develop it, test it and write it up.